# How to scrape yahoo finance news headers with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape news from yahoo's finance, for a pair.

How does `bs4`'s `find()` or `find_all()` work?

for this example:

[image]

with this [link](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD%3DX?p=EURUSD%3DX):

I'm traying to extract the data ... but no data is scraped. why? what's wrong?

I'm using this, but nothing is printed (except the tickers)

```
html = BeautifulSoup(source_s, "html.parser")  # "html")
            
            news_table_s = html.find_all("div",{"class":"Py(14px) Pos(r)"})
            
            news_tables_s[ticker_s] = news_table_s
        print("news_tables", news_tables_s)
```

I would like to extract the headers from a yahoo finance web page.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Would be great -Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate your `ResultSet` to get anything out.

```
for e in html.find_all("div",{"class":"Py(14px) Pos(r)"}):
    print(e.h3.text)
```

Recommendation - Do not use dynamic classes to select elements use more static ids or HTML structure, here selected via [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```
for e in html.select(' div:has(>h3>a)'):
        print(e.h3.text)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD%3DX?p=EURUSD%3DX'

html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
            
for e in html.select(' div:has(>h3>a)'):
    print(e.h3.text)
```

##### Output

```
EUR/USD steadies, but bears sharpen claws as dollar feasts on Fed bets
EUR/USD Weekly Forecast – Euro Gives Up Early Gains for the Week
EUR/USD Forecast – Euro Plunges Yet Again on Friday
EUR/USD Forecast – Euro Gives Up Early Gains
EUR/USD Forecast – Euro Continues to Test the Same Indicator
Dollar gains as inflation remains sticky; sterling retreats
Siemens Issues Blockchain Based Euro-Denominated Bond on Polygon Blockchain
EUR/USD Forecast – Euro Rallies
FOREX-Dollar slips with inflation in focus; euro, sterling up on jobs data
FOREX-Jobs figures send euro, sterling higher; dollar slips before CPI
```